# how to install apache spark on a aws ec2 free tier account cost free

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I am testing apache spark on my aws free tier account following this [tutorial](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ec2-scripts.html). However it creates 2 new instances (1x master and 1x slave) which means I wouldn't be able to run my machines for the whole month...

**Question:** Is there a way I can install apache spark on one single machine?

thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was easy... follow the instructions to setup apache spark as a standalone server [link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#cluster-launch-scripts)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just testing Spark you actually don't need to "install" spark. I do all my Spark development in a local VM running in local mode, but you can do the same thing in AWS with these steps:

1. Download Spark: http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html I typically go for the "Pre-built for Hadoop 2.6 and later" (don't worry, you don't need Hadoop whatsoever)
2. scp the tar to your machine, unpack somewhere like /opt or /usr/share
3. That's it!

You can run the spark shell:

```
/opt/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-shell
```

You can run packaged spark applications in local mode:

```
/opt/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-submit --master local[*] --class com.example.project.class project-1.0.jar
```

You can start Spark:

```
/opt/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin/start-all.sh
```

And hit the Spark UI at port 8080

Comment: thanks kruthar, I would like to have it installed on aws for a demo

Comment: Sorry I did not make myself clear, these steps work just as well on an AWS machine.

Comment: thanks @kruthar, I tried that but I am getting an failed to launch org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master:
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)